# Is there a PHP 5.3 bug concerning json_decode returning NULL on valid JSON strings?

Tags: php, json

I wrote an API for a friend's wordpress site that relies on the JSON API plugin to get a JSON feed of her recent posts.  It worked flawlessly for months, but a few days ago, stopped working entirely just when her shared host made the switch over to PHP 5.3 (of course, they did not alert their users-- why should they?)

I dug around and found a strange error in the part of the code that takes a JSON string, and returns the decoded JSON object to another function. Previously, the code (which worked, I SWEAR!) worked like this:

```
    $json_string = file_get_contents($url_to_json_string);
    return json_decode($json_string);
```

This began to return NULL, and json_last_error was 4 (syntax error.)  I checked the utf8_encoding: fine.  I checked for BOM-strangeness (according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-php)): fine.  I validated the JSON string in [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and in [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr) and it was perfectly valid.  No stray htmlentities, no wandering slashes.  The JSON string itself was fine and should have validated.

Then, I changed the code to this:

```
    $json_string = file_get_contents($url_to_json_string);
    $json_object = json_decode($json_string);
    return $json_object;
```

and it worked.

Does anyone know why this happened?

Comment: Can you provide the JSON which can not be parsed?

Comment: sure... it's kind of too long to post here, but this is an example that you can copy/paste yourself: http://tomtommag.com/?json=get_category_posts&count=1&category_id=105

Comment: It may be something as simple as a change in the config to not allow urls to open from fopen. Check phpinfo.

Comment: @MetalFrog i thought that was the error, too, at first.  but config did allow allow_url_open.

Comment: @HarloHolmes Oh well, it'd have been nice if that was the case! I hate when things (seemingly) randomly break.

Comment: Check the return value of that function. It can return NULL in two cases: On error or when the json was just NULL. For the error case, you need to call a function then to find out a) if it was an error and b) which one. do the error checking and logging(!) so next time this happens you have *more* information. PHP tells you if there was a syntax problem with json.

Comment: @hakre unfortunately, my error logs only point to the cascade of failure stemming from using an object that does not exist (ie "Trying to get property of non-object" and "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array") which are only thrown when the JSON string fails to resolve (thus resulting JSON object is null.)  My log shows no other errors.  As stated in the original post, json_last_error was 4.  Are there any other places I should look for errors that might shed more light on this?

Comment: `json_decode` with `json_last_error()` being 4 (most likely that is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`) tells you that this is not valid json. So this is merely about proper error handling I'd say. Are you familiar with the concept of defensive programming?

Comment: @hakre not explicitly, but it seems like you're saying I shouldn't count on the JSON string being 100% valid in the first place, and that I can hedge against that by applying some preemptive regex or something similar?

Answer (score 4):

The non printable characters must be in JSON string.
Use below:

```
json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $json_string);, true );
```

Comment: you have needless semicolon, correct syntax "json_decode( preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $json_string), true );"

Answer (score 3):

These links might be applicable:

- [json_decode() returns null issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/json-decode-returns-null-issues)
- https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/142
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45791

PS:

I just ran your snippet through a couple of validators: I did *not* see anything wrong ... but you might:

- http://www.functions-online.com/json_decode.html
- http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: thanks, @paulsm4 for the link to functions-online-- i didn't know that  one before!  but you and i are right, and so are the validators: the problem doesn't appear to be with the JSON string itself.  and, once i got it working again, there was no need to reformat the string with regex or anything.  so i'm still stumped!

Answer (score 0):

There is general bug in jsonDecode where "id":"google:1111111111111111111111111111111111111" is translated to "id:"google:"11111111111111111111111111"" which leads to syntax error.

To fix it the line must be:
$json_without_bigints = preg_replace('/:\s*(-?\d{'.$max_int_length.',})/', ': "$1"', $input);

(it must be : in regular expression in the front).