# PHP Json_Decode return Null

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call)

I am developing a REST service oriented App, in that on the place of login , i post the username and password it returns a json of following

`{"id":"4","username":"sam","redirect":"clients/home"}`

after that when i try to json_decode(), it showing NULL, can you tell me what is the problem
my server is PHP 5.2.12 and it support JSON_Decode.

```
function login()
{
    $result=$this->rest->request("http://localhost/account/users/login","POST");
    $qry['result']=json_decode($result);
    var_dump($qry['result']);
    foreach($qry as $result)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('id',$result->id);
        $this->session->set_userdata('username',$result->username);
        redirect($result->redirect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us more of your code, there should be nothing wrong so far with this...

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON validates using JSONLint. It might be unwanted spaces or characters that gets passed via the url. I think if you were to add the clean JSON string this problem might no occur. Try adding [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) after `json_decode()` to determine the exact problem. It should be something like:

```
        $qry['result']=json_decode($result);
        switch(json_last_error())
        {
            case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
                $error =  ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
                break;
            case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
                $error = ' - Unexpected control character found';
                break;
            case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
                $error = ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
                break;
            case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
            default:
                $error = '';                    
        }
        if (!empty($error))
            throw new Exception('JSON Error: '.$error);
```

Comment: My Server is 5.2 last_error() will not work on it

Answer (score 0):

Look onto this links

[PHP json_decode() returns NULL with valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json)

[json_decode() returns null issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/json-decode-returns-null-issues)

[json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-php)

I think it is because of `UTF-8 BOM`

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $d = stripslashes($result);
}else{
  $d = $result;
}
$d = json_decode($d,true);
```

try in this format.