# How do I manipulate the following string so that json_decode() can accept it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

This is my problem:

- The user provides the following string in a text input element(It's a url to a location on google maps):
  https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B048'45.7%22N+73%C2%B036'22.2%22W/@40.8130626,-73.6039651,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en
- I take the string value above via jquery along with some other text inputs, store it in an object, convert the values into a JSON String, and post it to the server for processing via ajax.
- Once the server receives it(I use php on the server side), I take the JSON string and provide it as an argument for json_decode(). json_decode() returns null indicating that there was an error in the formatting of the JSON string it received. I know the part of the JSON string that was at fault was the one I listed above because my script works if it's not included.

My question is. How do I manipulate the string above to make it work with json_decode()? JSONLint.com tells me that the string above is valid JSON. I've looked at these following posts and tried out suggested solutions such as utf8_encode() and bin2hex() to clean up the string;however, json_decode() still returns null:

- [json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call)
- [json_decode() returns null issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/json-decode-returns-null-issues)

I now know that there are encoding issues; however, I'm at a loss with regards to how to make the string above compatible with json_decode(). I don't post on SO unless I'm really stuck with an issue, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us your JSON string

Comment: Hmm. Can you decode that using `utf-8`?

Comment: {
    "rowTitle": "test",
    "rowSubtitle": "test",
    "rowDescription": "",
    "rowBackgroundColor": "",
    "rowCompact": "",
    "rowFavorite": "",
    "rowImage": "",
    "linkName1": "google location",
    "linkRoute1": "www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B048'45.7%22N+73%C2%B036'22.2%22W/@40.8130626,-73.6039651,15z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en"
}

Comment: I made 1 minor edit in the string above^. I deleted http:// from the url string, so that SO wouldn't use it as a link

Comment: Have you tried using [`json_last_error()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to get the details of the error?

Comment: Yes, I got (int) 4 returned using json_last_error().