# json_decode return null with different qoute

Tags: php, json

`json_decode('["foo","bar"]', true)`, this works, but this return `NULL`, `json_decode("['foo','bar']", true)`. The `json_last_error()` outputs `4`, `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`.

I've checked some answers from following questions;

[json_decode() returns null issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/json-decode-returns-null-issues)

[PHP json_decode() returns NULL with valid JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410342/php-json-decode-returns-null-with-valid-json)

[json_decode returns NULL after webservice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689185/json-decode-returns-null-after-webservice-call)

and tried following solutions but no success;

`json_decode(str_replace('&quot;', '"', "['foo','bar']"), true)`

`json_decode(stripslashes(str_replace('\"', '"', "['foo','bar']")), true)`

`json_decode(stripslashes("['foo','bar']"), true)`

`json_decode(utf8_encode("['foo','bar']"), true)`

I don't think it has to do with UTF-8 bom. Is it a PHP bug? Or how do I do turn `"['foo','bar']"` into `'["foo","bar"]'` as a workaround?

Comment: The string the the function `json_decode` takes as a parameter needs to be valid JSON. `{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}` this is valid JSON. You are just passing in an array wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON strings are quoted with double quotes `"`. Single quotes `'` (which are common in PHP) are not valid JSON. No discussion. Thus, the input `['foo','bar']` **is not valid json and `json_decode` correctly refuses to parse it**.

Also see [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), which defines the JSON format:

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022).<sup>1</sup>

If you're looking for something to transform your JSON-ish string (where does it come from? Fix the source of the invalid JSON, preferably) into valid JSON; `str_replace('\'', '"', $jsonInput)` should work in simple cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>(`U+0022` is the double quote `"`)

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing valid json to a function. If u using javascript array

```
    ["foo","bar"]
```

You should use JSON.stringify to make JSON actually on js side.