# json_decode returns null in PHPwhen passed JSONstring containg list of objects

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a JSON string containing list of objects and decode it in php using `json_decode()`, I've tried many posts on StackOverflow but nothing worked. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**JSON**

```
"[{"description":"null","endDate":"2017-04-17","endTime":"15:00:00","eventID":"vmkqad951217ifc2a1j5ic9154","eventTitle":"Some Task","startDate":"2017-04-17","startTime":"14:00:00"},{"description":"here\u0027s the description","endDate":"2017-04-20","endTime":"19:30:00","eventID":"eq5ddd8rbhctf8gfcjh7t9r3o8","eventTitle":"Another task","startDate":"2017-04-20","startTime":"18:30:00"},{"description":"null","endDate":"2017-04-21","endTime":"16:00:00","eventID":"6dnrh44jspqlslqpdnujpk9btg","eventTitle":"Twother task","startDate":"2017-04-21","startTime":"15:00:00"}]"
```

**PHP**

```
$d = $_POST['data'];
$ar = json_decode($d,true);
$obj = json_decode($d);
var_dump($ar,$obj);
```

if I `echo $d;` it shows perfect result but `var_dump($ar, $obj);` both are `NULL`

I've also read this so its not the same.
[json_decode() returns null issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110487/json-decode-returns-null-issues)

Comment: If you actually have `"` at the front and back, use `$d = trim($d,'"');` to strip those before decoding. See if that works

Comment: That's what [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/json_last_error) is for.. What does it say?

Comment: [Working fine here](https://3v4l.org/TW4hN), so I suspect you're having those extra quotes at the beginning + end actually in your string, causing the decode to fail.

Comment: @Rasclatt you are right........ its working now